# problem in window().set_timeout_with_callback_and_timeout_and_arguments_0 , how to setTimeout in rust-wasm correctly?

Tags: rust, wasm-bindgen, rust-wasm, wasm-pack, web-sys

I am building a snake game in web assembly, after lot of code commenting and un-commenting, i am seeing where it is giving me error, its giving me error in `window().set_timeout_with_callback_and_timeout_and_arguments_0 saying`

```
Uncaught Error: expected a number argument, found undefined
    at _assertNum (index_bg.js:246:1)
    at __wbg_adapter_27 (index_bg.js:257:1)
    at real (index_bg.js:214:1)
```

code snippet of the game loop:

```
fn game_loop(snake: Rc<RefCell<Snake>>, canvas: Rc<Canvas>, time: u32){
        let cl = Closure::<dyn FnMut(_)>::new(move |_: i32|{
            game_loop(snake.clone(), canvas.clone(), time);
            snake.borrow_mut().update();
            snake.borrow().draw(&canvas);
        });
        
        let _ = utils::window().set_timeout_with_callback_and_timeout_and_arguments_0(cl.as_ref().unchecked_ref(), 100);
    }

    game_loop(snake, Rc::new(canvas), 100);
```

github link: https://github.com/kshitijk83/snake-game

what i found: __wbg_adapter_27 is written like this->

```
function __wbg_adapter_27(arg0, arg1, arg2) {
    _assertNum(arg0);
    _assertNum(arg1);
    _assertNum(arg2);
    wasm._dyn_core__ops__function__FnMut__A____Output___R_as_wasm_bindgen__closure__WasmClosure___describe__invoke__hcf9afe44e302a4ef(arg0, arg1, arg2);
}
```

arg2 is undefined here it is expecting a num here.

I have tried set_timeout_with_callback_and_timeout_and_arguments_1 function passing it another argument it doesn't work.
i have gone through the doc and set_timeout_with_callback_and_timeout_and_arguments_0 definition looks same to me.

Answer (score 0):

I went throught web-sys docs and i found that I forgot to call closure.forget(), and I was using bad `_` in dyn Fn(_) which was giving time this error.
corrected code:

```
 fn game_loop(snake: Rc<RefCell<Snake>>, canvas: Rc<Canvas>, time: u32){
        let snake_clone = snake.clone();
        let canvas_clone = canvas.clone();
        let cl = Closure::<dyn Fn()>::new(move ||{
            snake_clone.borrow_mut().update();
            snake_clone.borrow().draw(&canvas_clone);
            game_loop(snake_clone.clone(), canvas_clone.clone(), time);
        });
        
        let _ = utils::window().set_timeout_with_callback_and_timeout_and_arguments_0(cl.as_ref().clone().as_ref().unchecked_ref(), 100);

        cl.forget();
    }
```